# Realizar request HttpPost sin esperar respuesta Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo un problema ya que consumo un servicio externo, pero solo lo necesito para notificar, dicho servicio en ocasiones tarda mucho en responder y afecta el tiempo de respuesta del mio, que debo hacer para que ejecute el servicio y no espere la respuesta para continuar con el flujo.

Mi proyecto es desarrollado en Spring Boot y utilizo HttpPost para mis peticiones

Comment: Hola, Chriz. Podrías colocar lo que llevas de código para poder darte una respuesta más específica a tu pregunta.

Comment: Si no necesitas esperar la respuesta, en principio podés correrlo en un Thread aparte.